# In File JSON editing without loading all data of the file

Tags: android, json

Currently i'm working on a webservice for android devices where a device can upload json data to a server (java webapp on tomcat8) which in turn saves the data into a db (mysql).

My problem is, that the data contains images and could grow to around 100 mb per upload file. The images shall not be uploaded separated from the other information.

So I need to put all the data in a single json and upload it.

I was wondering if it is possible with some json library to access the json file without fully loading it and add more data directly to the file.

An example given this classes:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Address address;
    private List<ImageData> data;

    public class Address {
        private String address;
        private String city;
        private String state;
    }

    public class ImageData {
        private String id;
        private String base64;
    }
}
```

A Person is generated like this:

```
public static String toJson(Person person) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("name", person.getName());
            jsonObject.put("surename", person.getSurname());

            JSONObject jsonAdd = new JSONObject();
            jsonAdd.put("address", person.getAddress().getAddress());
            jsonAdd.put("city", person.getAddress().getCity());
            jsonAdd.put("state", person.getAddress().getState());

            jsonObject.put("address", jsonAdd);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            for(Person.ImageData pn : person.getImageData()) {
                JSONObject jsonPhone = new JSONObject();
                jsonPhone.put("id", pn.getId());
                jsonPhone.put("base64", pn.getBase64());
                jsonArray.put(jsonPhone);
            }

            jsonObject.put("imageData", jsonArray);

            return jsonObject.toString();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

With an output like this:

```
{
        "imageData": [
        {
            "base64": "someimage", 
                "id": "11111"
        }
   ],
        "address": {
        "state": "somewhere",
                "address": "somewhere, 000",
                "city": "somewhere city"
    },
        "surname": "sure",
            "name": "last"
    }
```

To an existing Person with all fields filled and one Imagedata I want to add an additional ImageData without loading the whole JsonArray of type ImageData so the output would be this:

```
{
        "imageData": [
        {
            "base64": "someimage", 
                "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "base64": "someimage",
                "id": "2222"
        }
   ],
        "address": {
        "state": "somewhere",
                "address": "somewhere, 000",
                "city": "somewhere city"
    },
        "surname": "sure",
            "name": "last"
    }
```

Is it possible to directly edit the file without loading everything? Like searching the imagedata container but not loading the content (id and base64)  and then just adding an additional element (id, base 64) to the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to edit the json I got another idea instead of creating a big file for editing.

First I save the data without the pictures and only put filepaths to the images instead of the pictures into it.

Because i just need the JSON for uploading to a webservice I can generate it when all correct information is aquired.

So i prepare a JSON Builder for creating the large file which streams the given data into a new file using the Jackson Library using this dependency:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
...
}
```

And this Imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
```

In a method `buildLargeJson(File[], Person)` I first create a new file in the `public_storage/documents` then create a JsonGenerator for streaming the data via FileStream of the new file.

```
public static void buildLargeJson(File[] files, Person p) {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        File file = new File(dir, "large.json");

        try {
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(new FileWriter(file));
            generator.writeStartObject();
            generator.writeFieldName("name");
            generator.writeString(p.getName());
            generator.writeFieldName("surname");
            generator.writeString(p.getSurname());

            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                generator.writeFieldName("imageData");
                generator.writeStartArray();
                int counter = 1;
                for (File f : files) {
                    generator.writeStartObject();
                    generator.writeFieldName("id");
                    generator.writeNumber(counter++);
                    generator.writeFieldName("base64");
                    byte[] b = byteArrayFromFile(f);

                    if (b != null) {
                        generator.writeBinary(b);
                    } else {
                        generator.writeString("image not found");
                    }

                    b = null;

                    generator.writeEndObject();
                }
                generator.writeEndArray();
            }
            generator.writeEndObject();
            generator.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Using the Person class from the question i put in the information and add all pictures to the person. Pictures are of course saved as Base64 using the byte array of the image itself generated via `byteArrayFromFile(File)` method. The byte arrays are created via reading a FileInputStream of the image without loading the bitmap to save memory. Even for pictures of a size around 25MB the app only used less than 40MB of RAM for generating a 120MB JSON File.The conversion of byte to Base64 is done by the Jackson library Method `writeBinary(byte[])` of the `JsonGenerator`.

```
private static byte[] byteArrayFromFile(File imageFile) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        byte[] b = null;
        int bytesRead;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            b = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
        return b;
    }
```

Tested with Android API 19 and 25 standard WXGA Tablet Emulators and a Samsung A3 2016 (Nougat 7.0).